# Can't Cast to String Even With Operator Overloaded

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, casting, operator-overloading

Using MVC3 and the `StringLength` validation attribute on a property of type `MyType<string>` who's internal value is a `string`, I get an exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyType' to type 'System.String'.

So I added an operator overload, here's my class:

```
public class MyType<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    //...

    public static implicit operator string(MyType<T> instance)
    {
        //Return the internal value of the instance.
        return Convert.ToString(instance.Value);
    }
}
```

So this should, in theory, allow `MyType` to be cast to a `String`. However, I still get the same error, here is the stack trace:

> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'MyType' to type
>   'System.String'.]
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.StringLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value) +64
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.IsValid(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext) +176
>   System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult(Object
>   value, ValidationContext validationContext) +41
>   System.Web.Mvc.d__1.MoveNext() +267

The `StringLengthAttribute.IsValid` method (from the .NET framework, not my code) is doing this:

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    this.EnsureLegalLengths();
    int num = (value == null) ? 0 : ((string)value).Length;
    return value == null || (num >= this.MinimumLength && num <= this.MaximumLength);
}
```

Seems like it should work, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `value` is declared of type `object`.  You must first cast to the actual type first since the underlying object is not a `string`.  There are no conversions defined from `object` to other types so the cast you're doing is effectively telling the compiler that this object is actually a `string` when it is not.  This is essentially the same kind of rule that must be followed when unboxing value types.

By casting it to your type first, the compiler can then realize that a (implicit) conversion exists from your type to the desired `string` type and can generate the appropriate instructions.

e.g.,

```
object obj = new MyObject<string> { Value = "Foobar" };
string x = (string)obj;           // fail: obj is not a string
string y = (MyObject<string>)obj; // obj: obj is cast to MyObject<string> and
                                  //      an implicit cast to string exists
// to be clearer
string z = (string)(MyObject<string>)obj;
```

Comment: I don't think that's correct, the point of overloading an operator is so you can cast an object to another type. So `public static implicit operator string (MyType<T> instance)` returns a string representation of the object. Even though the `IsValid` method accepts an `object`, the framework knows what the underlying type is and you shouldn't have to explicitly cast it to that type first.

Comment: On second thought it seems that you're right; but I don't understand why. The framework *knows* what type of object it's trying to cast to a `string` and I told it how to do so. It seems it would check for the implicit conversion on the actual type, not the passed-in type.

Comment: At _runtime_ we can find out the actual types.  But here, the compiler can only use what is known at _compile time_. All we know is that we are given some object. The actual type of the object isn't really known, just that it is or derives from `object`. So at _compile time_, the only conversion from `object` that is known is a non-converting cast to the actual (or lesser derived) type. So the compiler generates the instructions to the the non-converting cast and that fails for the reasons I've explained above. If it was declared as `dynamic`, then the runtime could have done its magic.

Answer (score 0):

```
public override bool IsValid(object value)
{
    this.EnsureLegalLengths();
    int num = (value == null) ? 0 : ((MyType<string>)value).Value.Length;
    return value == null || (num >= this.MinimumLength && num <= this.MaximumLength);
}
```

Don't cast it to `string`, but to `MyType<string>`.

The changed line of code to reflect this is:

```
    int num = (value == null) ? 0 : ((MyType<string>)value).Value.Length;
```

**Edit**:  Don't pass `MyType<string>` to the method, pass `MyType<string>.Value` to it so that cast will be successful.

Comment: That code is from the .NET framework using ILSpy. That is in the `StringLengthAttribute` class.

Comment: @JoshM. Well you can't pass the type `MyType<string>` to that method, then.  Just pass `MyType<string>.Value`.  That will work for you, as that is the `string`.

Comment: It's all handled automatically in MVC, I'm not manually passing anything around, it happens during validation on the client side and again on postback.

Answer (score 0):

You are using implicit cast and you should do explicit cast because the framework cast it explicitly. Like this:

```
(string)value
```

You should add:

```
public static explicit operator string(MyType<T> instance)
{
    //Return the internal value of the instance.
    return Convert.ToString(instance.Value);
}
```

Comment: I did try an `explicit` operator instead but it didn't work - I'll try again. However, I believe if you define an `implicit operator`, that would suffice for both `explicit` and `implicit` casting...no?